# Why ? Datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

```
<script defer>
$(document).ready(function() {

    alert("FIRST ALERT MESSAGE (IT IS WORKING!)");

    var calcDataTableHeight = function() {
        return $(window).height()*39/100;
    };
    var oTable = $('#CariKart').dataTable({
    sScrollY: calcDataTableHeight(),
    bPaginate: false,
    bFilter: true,
    aaSorting: [[0,'asc']],
    oLanguage: {
        sZeroRecords: "Kayıtlı Cari Kart İşlemi bulunmamaktadır.",
        sInfo: "Listede toplam <b>_TOTAL_</b> Cari Kart İşlemi bulunmaktadır.",
        sInfoEmpty: "Kayıtlı Cari Kart İşlemi bulunmamaktadır.",
        sSearch: "İşlem Ara: "
    },
    aoColumns: [
            { sWidth: '15%' },
            { sWidth: '10%' },
            { sWidth: '21%' },
            { sWidth: '10%' },
            { sWidth: '10%' },
            { sWidth: '10%' },
            { sWidth: '10%' },
            { sWidth: '10%' },
            { sWidth: '4%' }
        ]
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
        oSettings.oScroll.sY = calcDataTableHeight();
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });

    alert("SECOND ALERT MESSAGE (IT IS NOT WORKING!)");
});
```

Can anyone explain why first alert message is working why second message is not working?

alert function is not neccessary! When I write any js code before datatable codes they are running but If I write them after datatable codes they dont. Why? :)

Comment: Do you get any exception? Check the console.

Comment: What happens if you remove the first alert message ?

Comment: That's a horrible title. Please read [ask].

Comment: I know datatables has a way of executing code when it is fully finished processing on the page. I wonder what would happen if you add your second alert to that property instead.

Comment: If I add jquery and datatables js to the page it prints both alerts for me.

Comment: Something between the two alerts must be getting an error that stops the function. Check your Javascript console for the error message.

Comment: Only reason is error must be being thrown....try using `.DataTable()` instead of `.dataTable()` and make sure you included plugin file and report what errors you have

Comment: When I remove the first alert still second alert dont work. datatable and calcDataTableHeight work good. but $(window).resize() and second alert dont work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one of the documented methods to access the [plugin API](https://datatables.net/manual/api)

One is to use `.DataTable()` instead of `.dataTable()`

You are most likely getting a *"not a function"* error in console